# Can't get an echo to do what I want in Wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

So I'm trying to write a new plugin since I haven't been able to find one that does exactly what I want with the extensibility that I desire. The goal of the plugin is to be able to use a simple shortcode to display an image slider that automatically populates with your blog's latest posts.

I've got the basic plugin files ready and the shortcode implemented and tested. I had a snafu solved yesterday on SO but the solution highlighted a new problem. Here's the code:

```
function slyd( $category, $slydcount ) {
    global $post;
    $tmp_post = $post;                                                                              // Create $tmp_post to empty $post once Slyd is done with it

    $args = array(
        'category'      =>  $category,
        'numberposts'   =>  $slydcount
    );
    $slydposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $slydposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);
        $post_title         =   get_the_title();                                                    // Get the post's title
        $post_content       =   get_the_content();                                                  // Get the post's content - will write code to get excerpt later
        $post_thumb         =   wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full' );     // Get the post's featured image's src
        $post_permalink     =   get_permalink();                                                    // Get the post's permalink
        echo '<h2><a href="' . $post_permalink . '">' . $post_title . '</a></h2>'
        . '<p>' . $post_content . '</p>'
        . '<p>' . $post_thumb . '</p>';
    endforeach;
    $post = $tmp_post;                                                                              // Empty $post once Slyd is done with it
}

// Create the shortcode
function slyd_shortcode( $atts ) {
    // $atts        ::=     array of attributes
    // examples:            [slyd]
    //                      [slyd category='slide']
    //                      [slyd slydcount='5']
    //                      [slyd theme='default']

    /* Retrieve attributes set by the shortcode and set defaults for
    unregistered attributes. */
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'category'      =>  'slyd',                                                                 // Which category(s) to display posts from
        'slydcount'     =>  '5',                                                                    // How many Slyds to display
        'theme'         =>  'default'                                                               // Which Slyd theme to use
    ), $atts ) );

    return "<p>category = {$category}, count = {$slydcount}</p>"
    . slyd( $category, $slydcount );
}

add_shortcode( 'slyd', 'slyd_shortcode' );
```

The issue is in the `foreach` loop in `function slyd();`. I was originally using a `return` where the `echo` is now to put the result on the screen. That worked to display the first post but it would, of course, escape the function. I need it to cycle through and display all of the posts.

From researching the PHP documentation I found that I could use `print` in place of `echo` or `return` but it's giving me the same result as `echo`. What's happening is the code seems to be executing twice. It places itself where it needs to be the first time, then it also echoes to the browser and places it just below the `head` of the page.

I suppose my question is whether there's an alternative to `return`, `echo`, or `print` that would solve my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Now I'm trying to get the plugin to pull in the blog's latest posts but I'm running into a bit of a snafu. When I use the_title() and the_permalink() they display outside of the code I'm trying to contain them in. Further, the_content() is displaying once with the_permalink() and the_title() and then a second time where it's supposed to.

You can see the behavior [here](http://acommunityofwomen.com/slider/).

Comment: For the record, while `echo` and `print` have the same functionality, `return` is completely different, don't know where you heard the three are exchangeble...When you use `return` the function stops there and returns (something or nothing), then exits from its routine. While if you use `echo` or `print` it doesn't stop processing.

Comment: Do you really need to have the `echo` in your `slyd` function?  What happens when you comment that out?

Comment: @DamienPirsy - Actually `return` is only different in that it exits the loop. Otherwise all three of them return a value. I already knew that and I knew the `return` was why my function was failing, I just didn't know how to fix it.
@seanbreeden - The `echo` (now a `return`) does need to be inside of the `slyd` function. Otherwise it would return the values for the Wordpress page instead of the most recent posts that I was trying to retrieve.

Comment: the echo prints a value, not returns it.

Comment: Let's put it like this, is like saying "the hell, here, I've finished my project" to your boss, turning your PC off and walking home straight away. Echo or print is like saying "here it's the finished project", and then starting to work on another. No, really, I'm not mothertongue so I can't explain well, but those are different construct, used for different purposes and in different situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` is what you want in this case. You want to return a value (i.e. html code) from the `slyd` function so you can use it (in this case append it) in the `slyd_shortcode` function. However, you need to first collect all output into an additional variable (`$ret` below), and *then* return that value:

```
function slyd( $category, $slydcount ) {
    global $post;
    $tmp_post = $post;
    $args = array(
        'category'      =>  $category,
        'numberposts'   =>  $slydcount
    );
    $slydposts = get_posts( $args );
    $ret = '';
    foreach( $slydposts as $post ) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        $post_title         =   get_the_title();
        $post_content       =   get_the_content();
        $post_thumb         =   wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full' );
        $post_permalink     =   get_permalink();
        $ret .= '<h2><a href="' . $post_permalink . '">' . $post_title . '</a></h2>'
        . '<p>' . $post_content . '</p>'
        . '<p>' . $post_thumb . '</p>';
    }
    $post = $tmp_post;                                                                  
    return $ret;
}
```

As you see you should first initialize the `$ret` variable with an empty string, then append to it on each iteration of the `foreach` loop. `return` is used to return the whole string *after* the loop.

Comment: Yep, that was the solution I needed! I was pretty sure I needed `return`, I just wasn't sure how to get it to run without exiting the loop. Thanks so much!

P.S. - I've never seen the `.=` operator before. Concatenate Equals is easily one of the coolest things ever. :-P